# How to make a rotation invariant LBP

Tags: design-patterns, binary, local, face

I am usin LBp patterns for object tracking. I am using the bytefish lbp code for opencv https://github.com/bytefish/libfacerec/blob/master/src/lbp.cpp. However this LBPs are not rotation invariant. I have read about rotation invariant LBPs but I was Not able to implement on this ELBP code. Can someone help I really appreciate any help.